# Connection refused when CURLing to docker container from within Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, python

I have a situation with a CI Pipeline I'm trying to implement using Jenkins and Docker .

Inside my pipeline I want to: download a python uwsgi web app, build it in a docker container, run it, then execute API tests against the container's endpoints.

Mentions:

- I am using a jenkins-docker image ran with docker.sock volume mounted
- I run the python web app in the docker container, with a volume mounted to docker.sock, so the container mounts on the docker host on the linux server (which also hosts my jenkins docker container)
- I exposed port 4000 on the python app, I can access the python web app endpoints from the Linux server (curl request), I can access it from the network via browser requests, but I cannot, for the life of me, access the endpoint from the jenkins pipeline

I get the error Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 4000: Connection refused. 
I also tried with localhost:4000, I get the same result

My pipeline looks like this

```
node {
def app

stage('Clone repository') {
    git 'https://github.com/....'
}

stage('Build image') {
    app = docker.build('img:tag', '.')
    sh 'docker run -d -p 4000:4000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock img:tag'
    sleep time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES'
    sh 'curl http://0.0.0.0:4000/api/hello'
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you!